# Find post adress in free text - C#

Tags: c#, text, preprocessor

I'm working (in C#) on post adress detector in free text. The format of adress is e.g.:

```
string text = "Adresa je Novakova (Street name) 36, PSC 46015, Usti nad Labem (name of city)"
```

I have string array (with several thousands strings) of City and Street names:

```
string[] names = new string[] { "Usti nad Labem", "Novakova", "Liberec", ... };
```

What is the fastest way how to find index of found string names (city or street) in text. Is it better to use HashSet or List? Thank you for your advice.

Comment: If you're sure you'll get direct hits on the corpus data, not much will match a `HashSet<string>`, but I suspect that accents (and other diacritics), capitalization and other variations will probably cause you significant problems. You could probably use a smarter/more tolerant `IEqualityComparer` for the hashset, or write one yourself, or in the extreme case, use a custom data structure such as a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Comment: Or leverage some capabilities at the database level (fulltext search / string collation)